# Use method of a fragment in a button inside a class extended from ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment and another class that I had extended from ArrayAdapter class.

**Now** I have a button inside that class and I want to use method of fragment.

```
public class ProfileAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Profile> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    private Context mContext;
    public ProfileAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
        this.mContext=context;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view=convertView;
        if(view==null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_item, null);
        }

        ImageButton btnDel=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDell);
        final Profile currentObject = getItem(position);
        final String type=currentObject.getType();

        btnDel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MainActivity.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                  builder.setMessage("do you want to delete profile")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setTitle("** Delete Profile **")
                    .setPositiveButton("yes",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        DbManager db=new DbManager(mContext);
                        int idd=Integer.parseInt(currentObject.getId());
                            db.deleteProfile(idd);
                           DisplayLocation dL=new DisplayLocation() //this is Fragment
;                          dL.removeProximity(idd);// i want to access this method



                       }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       }
                      });
                  AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                  alert.show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in one of my apps. Here is the code from the array adapter class that I used. The camping class is a fragment.

Did you remember to create a static instance of the fragment?

```
 final Camping camping = new Camping();
 btn = (ImageButton) otherView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    camping.list = db.getAllItemsCamping();
                    camping.adapt = new CustomAdapter1(getActivity(), R.layout.item_layout, camping.list);
                    camping.listItem = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_camp);
                    camping.listItem.setAdapter(camping.adapt);
                    camping.nothingtext = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.nothing_here_camp);
                    camping.count = camping.listItem.getCount();
                    if (camping.count > 0){
                        camping.nothingtext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else if (camping.count == 0){
                        camping.nothingtext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    Log.i("UpDateDataBase()", "Was Called");
                }
            });
```

Also, you seem to be missing a semi colon here `DisplayLocation dL=new DisplayLocation()`